# Why is this chai-as-promised AssertionError printing to the Console but not my Mocha test runner?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

I'm tyring to test some code that uses Promises with `chai-as-promised` and `Mocha`. My test suite is also utilizing [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) to mock AJAX requests that would normally be sent using the Fetch API.

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
/**
 * Sends a POST request to save (either insert or update) the record
 * @param  {object} record simple object of column name to column value mappings
 * @return {Promise}       Resolves when the POST request full response has arrived.
 * Rejects if the POST request's response contains an Authorization error.
 */
save(record) {
  var _this = this;
  return this._auth(record)
    .then(function() {
      return window.fetch(_this._getPostUrl(), {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: _this._objToPostStr(record),
        credentials: 'include'
      });
    })
    .then(function(saveResp) {
      return saveResp.text();
    })
    .then(function(saveResp) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (saveResp.indexOf('Authorization') !== -1) {
          reject('Request failed');
        } else {
          resolve(saveResp);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

In my most upper-level `describe`, I have this function that initially sets up my `fetchMock` object.

```
before(() => {
  fetchMock = new FetchMock({
    theGlobal: window,
    Response: window.Response,
    Headers: window.Headers,
    Blob: window.Blob,
    debug: console.log
  });
  fetchMock.registerRoute({
    name: 'auth',
    matcher: /tlist_child_auth.html/,
    response: {
      body: 'authResp',
      opts: {
        status: 200
      }
    }
  });
});
```

and here's the relevant test code:

```
describe('save', () => {
  it('save promise should reject if response contains the string Authorization', () => {

    fetchMock.mock({
      routes: ['auth', {
        name: 'save',
        matcher: /changesrecorded.white.html/,
        response: {
          body: 'Authorization',
          opts: {
            status: 200
          }
        }
      }]
    });

    let _getLocationStub = sinon.stub(client, '_getLocation');
    _getLocationStub.returns('/admin/home.html');

    client.foreignKey = 12345;
    let promise = client.save({
      foo: 'bar'
    });
    promise.should.eventually.be.fulfilled;
    fetchMock.unregisterRoute('save');
  });
});
```

The reason I'm defining the `save` route in the `fetchMock.mock()` call is I have another test that needs the `save` route to be redefined to return something else.

To make sure chai-as-promised is actually working and will notify me of failed tests, I wrote a failing test `promise.should.eventually.be.fulfilled;`. This will fail because the Promise returned by `save` will reject if the response contains `Authorization`, which it does. The Chrome Console shows the AssertionError with `message: expected promise to be fulfilled but it was rejected with 'Request failed`, but my Mocha `test-runner.html` page is showing that this test passed. For some reason, chai-as-promised isn't communicating properly with Mocha.

If you'd like to see my entire project, please see [this repo](https://github.com/IronCountySchoolDistrict/extended-schema-client-library) on Github.

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**

Here's my test setup code:

```
let expect = chai.expect;
mocha.setup('bdd');
chai.should();
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value `promise.should.eventually.be.fulfilled` is a promise, **which you should return so that Mocha can know when your test is over.** I've created a small test file to simulate what you were seeing and I can completely replicate the behavior if, like you do, I just fail to return `promise.should.eventually.be.fulfilled;`. Here is an example that works:

```
import chai from "chai";
import chaiAsPromised from "chai-as-promised";

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

describe("foo", () => {
    it("bar", () => {
        let promise = Promise.reject(new Error());
        return promise.should.eventually.be.fulfilled;
    });
});
```

In your code you had some cleanup code at the very end of your test: `fetchMock.unregisterRoute('save');`. Based on what you show, I'd move this to an `after` hook so that it mirrors your `before` hook. In general, `after` should perform cleanup that corresponds to what is in `before` and `afterEach` to what is in `beforeEach`. However, if you *need* to have cleanup code inside a test for some reason, you could do:

```
        function cleanup() {
            console.log("cleanup");
        }

        return promise.should.eventually.be.fulfilled.then(
            // Called if there is no error, ie. if the promise was
            // fullfilled.
            cleanup,
            // Called if there is an error, ie. if the promise was
            // rejected.
            (err) => { cleanup(); if (err) throw err; });
```

Unfortunately, Chai seems to return something which looks like a ES6 `Promise` but only partially. Eventually, it will probably return a actual ES6 promise, and then you'll be able to call `.finally` to run cleanup code no matter what happens and have the error automatically propagate up.

Comment: It seems so obvious that the docs were saying this all along after reading this. Thanks for a great answer!